# How do I set timeout after button has been clicked in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need a background colour to go back to its default colour after 3 seconds, I am using the setTimeout method but it is not working, how do I properly use it in this situation? or do I use a transition

```
<div id="exercise">

    <div>
      <p>Current Value: {{ value }}</p>
      <button @click="value += 5(); red();" :style="{ 'background-color': color }">Add 5</button>
      <button @click="value += 1">Add 1</button>
      <p>{{ result }}</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="timer">
      <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#exercise",
  data: {
    value: 0,
    timer: 1000,
    color:'pink',


  },
  methods:{
  red() {
   this.color = "red";
setTimeout(function() {
        this.red = 0;
      }, 1000); 
  }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function() {
      return this.value >= 37 ? "Not there yet" : "done";
    }
  },
  watch: {
    result: function(value) {
      var vm = this;
      console.log(value);
      setTimeout(function() {
        vm.value = 0;
      }, 5000);
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: @click="value += 5(); red();"  what do (); after number 5 stand for?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use an arrow function for your setTimeout, as the setTimeout points the **this** to the global object. Arrow functions use lexical scoping and knows to bind the **this** to the inner function:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#exercise",
  data: {
    value: 0,
    timer: 1000,
    color:'pink',


  },
  methods:{
  red() {
   this.color = "red";
setTimeout(() => {
        this.color = "";
      }, 1000); 
  }
  },
  computed: {
    result: function() {
      return this.value >= 37 ? "Not there yet" : "done";
    }
  },
  watch: {
    result: function(value) {
      var vm = this;
      console.log(value);
      setTimeout(function() {
        vm.value = 0;
      }, 5000);
    }
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="exercise">
    <div>
      <p>Current Value: {{ value }}</p>
      <button @click="red();" :style="{ 'background-color': color }">Add 5</button>
      <button @click="value += 1">Add 1</button>
      <p>{{ this.result }}</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="timer">
      <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

(Also, inside of your setTimeout, you were trying to change **this.red = 0**, when it should be **this.color = ""** :D

Comment: @Adoga Patricia Did this solve your original question?